# Is it possible to seperate wordpress menu by different div?

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm looking for a way to display a WordPress menu separating its links into different divs like this:

```
<div class="col-2-4">
    <p><a href="">link</a></p>
    <p><a href="">link</a></p>
    <p><a href="link"></a></p>
</div>

<div class="col-3-4">
    <p><a href="">link</a></p>
    <p><a href="">link</a></p>
    <p><a href="link"></a></p>
</div>

<div class="col-4-4">
    <p><a href="">link</a></p>
    <p><a href="">link</a></p>
    <p><a href="link"></a></p>
</div>
```

And if there is no way I don't mind going back to the list way.

Comment: Are the divs different menus or children? Could you edit your question and put in the traditional menu ( in list-item form ). How do you know when to separate into different divs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, please take a look at the code below it will give you the basic idea. You can change ul to div and add some logic to match your needs.

```
$menu_name = 'primary';
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
$menu_list = '<ul id="menu-' . $menu_name . '">';
foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $title = $menu_item->title;
    $url = $menu_item->url;
    $menu_list .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
}
$menu_list .= '</ul>';
```

Here's a good reference : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/